# How to use slider like changer over image to replace with another images

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

All
I want to make a image "slider" which will uncover the image underneath it when the user grabs the handle and drags it.

http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/1/

In this example, the user grabs the handle and moves it on the slider. I would like the same thing, but revealing the image behind it.

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#slider {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(nTo) {
    nTo = nTo || 10;
    return Math.round(this * (1 / nTo) ) * nTo;
}

$(function() {
    var slides = $('#slider ul').children().length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $("#slider ul").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).animate({'left': (ui.position.left).roundTo(slideWidth)})
        }
    });
});
```

Result image will change like this if we drag from pivot point

**By replacing the image in background  Both image are come parallel While i want they overlay on each other as display in 2nd picture**

Current Results 
[image]

Desire Results :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="slider">
<ul>
    <li style="background-image: url('path to image')"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('path to image')"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('path to image')"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain this ?

Comment: Your code in fiddle is working fine. instead of using background-color for each li use background-image:url('path to image') so that instead of colored background you get images for li

Comment: Background is not help sir  i upload image and edit question have a look